# Import reg key using a bat file

Tags: batch-file, startup, regedit

The issue is that an update pushed to my devices keeps setting the NumLock to on and the users have to turn it off in order to log in on the laptops. I want the NumLock to be off and I need to check to see if it has been changed to on and change it back to off.

I have a registry key that I want to drop into remote computers' startup folder so it will run without any intervention, i.e. UAC, or "Are you sure?".

The key I need to change is:
"HKEY_Users.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard\InitialKeyboardIndicators" /v 0 /t REG_SZ /f

The value I want to change is 2 and I need it to be v/0 to turn off the NumLock keyboard feature before users ever log in on the laptops.

I have exported this key and named it NumLockEdit.reg and can run it in a bat file as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF

NumLockEdit.reg
```

But, I want to have it run without any input from me or the user. No UAC or "Are you sure" questions.

I've also tried this,

```
@echo off

reg add "HKEY_Users\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard\InitialKeyboardIndicators" /v 0 /t REG_SZ /f
```

I've even tried creating a shortcut to my bat file and running it as admin but I still get the UAC and Are you sure? message.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: There seem to be other ways to get this done: https://www.technipages.com/enable-disable-numlock-windows-startup

Comment: Are you  sure that this is what you need? The subkey `HKEY_USERS\.Default` is not for all users, it is for the SYSTEM user. If you want to affect a change for all users, you'd need to load, modify, and unload each of the local hives for any users who are not logged in, the HKEY_CURRENT_USER subkey for the current user, and the HKEY_USERS\S-IDs subkeys of any other appropriate logged in users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKU.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard' -Name "InitialKeyboardIndicators" -Value "2"

Comment: Please consider explaining what your solution is doing and formatting accordingly

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I decided to go with a .reg file I created:                                             
 Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard]
"InitialKeyboardIndicators"="0"
"KeyboardDelay"="1"
"KeyboardSpeed"="31" which works perfectly.